# User Profile different across stack sites

Tags: support, profile-page, users, user-accounts

I've noticed differences in common profile information across the difference stack exchange sites. For instance:

- User description is different on Area51 than on StackOverflow
- My reputation continues to be reported different from each site

  **EDIT**: meaning for example, my SO rep is different when viewed from different stacks (Code Review, Programmers, Area51, etc.)
- "Recent names" is inconsistent across sites.

I know some of this can be caching issues, like with reputation, but these issues have lingered.

Also, for clarification, I have only ever used one Gmail account to OpenID onto these stacks.

Why would they be different?

Comment: Your Stack Overflow reputation seems to be shown consistently across sites at the moment (1815). Are you still seeing a discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your description on sites can be different but it is possible to sync it across sites by editing it and pressing "Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts".
- Your reputation is different on the different sites because [it does indeed differ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146610/one-beat-consumer?tab=accounts).

Comment: Thanks for letting know about the `Copy Profile` function. As for the reputation - yes, of course they differ on other stacks - that's not what I asked. I am saying, my rep reported for SO from Area51 is different than my SO reputation when viewing from my Code Review profile. My SO rep should be the same no matter what stack im on.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer - caching. The scores on the accounts tab of your profile are cached and hence not always consistent with your score on the site itself.

Comment: @Scrooge - seriously? look at my post. they have continue to mismatch cross browser, after cache dumps.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: Server-side caching.